Fixed number of cells per page for individual pieces of text
Using Google Docs or maybe some other tool, how to divide every page in a fixed number of cells (of fixed size) and insert a piece of text in each of them ? This for later cutting them into small pieces of paper with one piece of text on them.
I have 12000 individual pieces of text so copy-pasting them individually is out of the question.
Also I tried creating a table on each page and copy-pasting the whole text with the line breaks/carriage returns in one cell, hoping that during pasting, the carriage returns would cause the remainder of the text to be pasted in the next cell (kind of like Google Spreadsheet or Excel goes to the next cell when pressing enter) but it didn't do that, and instead the whole text (all 12000 pieces separated carriage returns) was pasted as a whole in the first cell.
I also tried creating a fixed number of text columns and then forcing more space between paragraphs until I had the desired number of lines on one page, but then if a piece of text extends on more than one line then everything is shifted down (whereas it could just extend over some blank space, thus locally reducing the page space between two pieces of text - which is no issue for me. What I want is that there be a fixed number of text pieces vertically on one page).

=SORT(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(12000)/0,"My_Text"))

IFERROR  SEQUENCE  SORT

SEQUENCE creates a 12,000 number array in a single column.
Dividing all the numbers by zero creates 12,000 #DIV/0! errors
IFERROR replaces each error with "My_Text"
The preceding is placed inside SORT which is an array function. INDEX or ARRAYFORMULA (or others) could be substituted in, but SORT is less characters.

You could change the dimensions to 3,000 rows x 4 columns as follows:
=SORT(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(3000,4)/0,"My_Text"))

